# Does AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.bind() always need "localhost"?

Tags: java, sockets, io

I am studing java socket. There is  a class Named "AsynchronousServerSocketChannel"

It has a method named "bind".And that method needs a "parameter" which is "SocketAddress".

I found that all example about the "SocketAddress" object are "new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8000)" or new InetSocketAddress("localhost",8000),

I want ask: "Is there any different situation that we use other ip-address, such as '192.168.1.100'? If there is not, why we have to always put it into the method. It should have a default one.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use any other local IP address, if you want the server to listen at only that address.
- More normally, you use `null,` or omit the parameter, which corresponds to `INADDR_ANY,` which means to accept connections via *any* local IP address.

Comment: You mean if I use that parameter, for example "127.0.0.1", 8000, so if the client want to conntect "192.168.1.100", 8000, it cannot be contect?